# UnitConvert of a Quantity whose value is a function of a Quantity

Tags: units

I am having trouble with `UnitConvert` when the `QuantityMagnitude` contains an embedded `Quantity` of its own. Here's an example of what happens, read on for my specific application. I would expect the last two outputs to be equal, but they are not.

Input:

```
Quantity[f[Quantity[x, "Meters"]], "Seconds"]
UnitConvert[%, "Hours"]
QuantityMagnitude[%] // FullForm
%[[2, 1]]
UnitConvert[%, Quantity["Feet"]]
UnitConvert[Quantity[x, "Meters"], Quantity["Feet"]]
```

Output:

```
f[x m] s
f[Quantity[x,CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`Meters]]/3600 h
Times[Rational[1,3600],f[Quantity[x,CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`Meters]]]
Quantity[x,CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`Meters]
UnitConvert[Quantity[x,CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`Meters],1 ft]
(1250 x)/381 ft
```

I have a rule defined to work on only `Quantity` parameters of the correct units, like so, which does some basic unit conversion and passes its magnitude to a numeric function:

```
f[Quantity[x_, ("Meters")^-1]] :> 
 f2[QuantityMagnitude@
   UnitConvert[Quantity[x, ("Meters")^-1], ("Angstroms")^-1]]
```

The result is dimensionless (`f2` is looking up a ratio at some physics wavenumber).

I then multiply that dimensionless result by a `Quantity` with complicated units for a later calculation. I can simplify the complicated units using `UnitConvert`, which can only be done if the whole expression is a `Quantity`, so I bring the `f[x]` inside to multiply the value of the complicated units (see [my earlier question here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76818/working-with-symbolic-values-in-quantities)). But when I try to simplify the complicated units using `UnitConvert`, it replaces the "Meters" unit with the symbol

```
CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`Meters
```

which I suspect is never meant to be seen. In any case, the `Quantity` that it is a part of no longer works as a regular `Quantity` with functions like `UnitConvert` or even `QuantityMagnitude`.

Is this a bug? What can I do to work around it?

Comment: In *Mathematica* 10.0.2.0, the last two outputs are equal. More specifically: I do not see the `CalculateUnits``UnitCommonSymbols``Meters` anywhere in my output. Which version are you using? Maybe you need to try it in a new *Mathematica* session to avoid possibly conflicting definitions elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get that same odd result w/v9

you might try something like this as a workaround..

```
 unitConvert[Quantity[mag_, unit_], tounit_] :=
      Quantity[ QuantityMagnitude[#]  mag  ,
           QuantityUnit[#] ] &@ UnitConvert[Quantity[1, unit], tounit]

 unitConvert[Quantity[f[Quantity[x, "Meters"]], "Seconds"], "Hours"]
```

> Quantity[f[Quantity[x, "Meters"]]/3600, "Hours"]

Comment: Yes, I'm using 9.0.2, so I suppose it is a bug that's been fixed in 10. That work around works well enough, just a shame that it needs to be used.